# Why is my Ctrl-key disabled in iTerm.app?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, iterm

I'm trying to use [the new iTerm app](http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/) on my Snow Leopard Mac, but my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> seems to be completely dead (as in non-responsive, as in nothing happens when I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> except for an outputed 'a') and I haven't found anything useful while googling. The closest match was [this thread here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951361/leopard-terminal-and-iterm-ignores-control-key-combos), but **everything in Terminal.app works as it should**.

And, even more strange - I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> myself out of applications, but I can't save files in Emacs (`C-x C-s`) or any other keyboard shortcuts that uses a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> shortcut. And it's not local, since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is as broken on my iMac as it is on other unix computers I've sshed onto with iTerm. I've tried both in bash and zsh.

I've tried to remove all files concerning iTerm.app in my `~/Library/Application Support`, and I've tried the very latest version (currently 13 h old) of iTerm I could lay my hands on, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a guess: Have you checked `~/.inputrc`?

Comment: Just wondering, should this question be tagged with `bash`?

Comment: If you run `stty`, what is the output?  How does the `stty` output compare to other terminals (e.g. you say it works in Apple's Terminal)?  Also check the Preferences, "Keys" pane in iTerm2 because you might need to fix the setting that remaps the Control key to something else.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an iTerm bug.

You can work around it by creating a key mapping in the profile settings.
Add a mapping for `^x` so it sends `0x18` (which is the encoded form of ctrl+x).

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check this post to see if the ctrl key is enabled in your preferences

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52041/how-to-press-control-key-on-mac

Did you try to configure key bindings for this terminal emulator as specified in the iTerm wiki:

http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/Keybindings

at last, have you try `set -o emacs` or `set -o vi`?

If it works, set it in your ~/.bashrc to run it at login.