# iTerm Emacs key codes for Ctrl + <Arrow Keys>

Tags: macos, bash, emacs, iterm

In Emacs on Linux terms and Cygwin, Ctrl + Up/Down causes a long jump (depending on the mode) say one function block down, on iTerm however this does not work I am assuming I need to manually set key codes send?

Comment: Fond a similar post on SO, will that solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951361/leopard-terminal-and-iterm-ignores-control-key-combos

Comment: not really, in my case ctrl + a,e etc does work but ctrl up-arrow does not.

Comment: ok, seemed like a good candidate, i'm not on osx so I cannot test...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using iTerm 2. Go to Preferences window in iTerm, and check both "Keys" tabs. One is in the main tabs and the second is for each profile. By default, in the "Keys" tab in your profile <kbd>^↑</kbd> are <kbd>^↓</kbd> are defined there to send some backward-compatible special keys. Remove them for your profile and you're good to go!

**UPDATE:** This change doesn't seem to affect your current tab or window. You may need to start a new iTerm window.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>M-{</kbd> and <kbd>M-}</kbd> instead.